# Jenkins: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have code that reads in a pom.xml file then attempts to re-serialize and write it back out:

```
// Get the file raw text

def pomXMLText = readFile(pomFile)

// Parse the pom.xml file

def project = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(pomXMLText)

... do some useful stuff ...

def pomFileOut = "$WORKSPACE/pomtest.xml"

def pomXMLTextOut = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(project)

println "pomXMLTextOut = $pomXMLTextOut" // <-- This line prints to updated XML
```

> writeFile file: pomFileOut, text: pomXMLTextOut // <-- This line crashes with the error listed in the posting title: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild

I've tried casting the pomXMLTextOut variable to a String. I tried applying the .text() method, which gets a jenkins sandbox security error. Has anyone else been able to successfully write an XML file from a groovy script running in a Jenkins pipeline?

BTW, I've also tried using a File object, but that isn't remotable across jenkins nodes. It works as long as the job always runs on master.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a @NonCPS annotation and close those non-serializable objects in a funcation like this

```
@NonCPS
def writeToFile(String text) {
    ...
}
```

Here's the explanation from [Pipeline groovy plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md)

> @NonCPS methods may safely use non-Serializable objects as local
>   variables